# Clearing the confusion of the area

Tags: geometry

In the example 1:

They are finding the area as $8$ $\sqrt[2]{30}$. But, I am finding $8$ $\sqrt[2]{15}$.

I have done $\sqrt[2]{16\times5\times8\times3}$

Then,

Breaking it up,

$2\times2\times2\times\sqrt[2]{15}$

Please help me clear my confusion.

[image]

Comment: The $16\times 8$  inside the square root is $(8)(8)(2)$. So we want $\sqrt[2]{(8)(8)(2)(5)(3)}$.

Comment: Can we write it as $\sqrt[2]{2*2*2*2*2*2*5*3}$

Comment: Your count is wrong. There are $7$ (seven) $2$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$16 = 2^4$

$8 = 2^3$

$\sqrt{(16)(8)(5)(3)} = \sqrt{(2^4)(2^3)(5)(3)} = \sqrt{(2^{3+4})(5)(3)} = \sqrt{(2^6)(2)(5)(3)}$

$= \sqrt{(8^2)(2)(5)(3)} = 8\sqrt{(2)(5)(3)} = 8 \sqrt{30}$

You honestly just took out an extra two. Happens to the best of us. 
 :)

Comment: Thank you! Got the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just forgetting to multiply by two.

Note that

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{16\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdot 3} &= \sqrt{4 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}\\
&= \sqrt{4}\sqrt{4}\sqrt{4}\sqrt{5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}\\
&= 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}\\
&= 8 \sqrt{5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}\\
&= 8 \sqrt{30}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh yeah! Silly mistake of mine. Thanks for the help though.